# Морфологічна будова слова колишній

Tags: словотворення, морфологія

Зацікавив склад прикметника *колишній*. Корінь коли, суфікс -н-, закінчення -ій. А що то за ш всередині?
За класифікацією суфіксів, наведеною у [монографії](http://booksshare.net/index.php?id1=4&category=lunguistics&author=gorpinich-vo&book=1999&page=12) В.О.Горпинича,

> Мутаційні — це такі суфікси, які змінюють лексичне значення твірного
>   слова незалежно від його частиномовної належності: -тель (виховувати —
>   вихователь), -ниц-я (телята — телятниця).
>
> Транспозиційні — це такі суфікси, які змінюють частиномовну
>   приналежність твірного слова при збереженні його основного лексичного
>   значення: -ість (ніжний — ніжність), -изн-а (голубий — голубизна),
>   -анн-я (малювати — малювання), -к-a (обмотати — обмотка).
>
> Модифікаційні — це такі суфікси, які не змінюють ні частиномовної
>   належності, ні лексичного значення твірного слова, а вносять у нього
>   якісно-кількісний або емоційно-оціночний відтінок: -ець (двигун —
>   двигунець), -к-a (ягода — ягідка), -як (вишня — вишняк). В українській
>   мові один і той самий суфікс може виконувати не одну, а кілька
>   функцій: -к-а — мутац. ватяний — ватянка, транспоз. підтримати —
>   підтримка, модиф. п’яниця — п'яничка; -ик — мутац. взуття —
>   взуттьовик, модиф. кінь — коник.

Але цей -ш- у слові колишній не виконує жодну із окреслених функцій. То навіщо він у цьому слові і звідки взявся?

Answer (score 4):

Декотрі ролї і причини відкостї розглянуто в статтї [*Західнополіські відприслівникові прикметники з формантом **-ішн-ій***](http://library.zu.edu.ua/vz/6/st_55_58.pdf) (Григорій Аркушин). Якщо спростити…

Варіянти кваліфікацій цего форманта:

1. Згадане: суфікс *-н-*, інтерфікс *-ш-*.

   Де [*інтерфікс*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81) (також називають *асантема*) — це такий структурний елемент у складї слова, що має матеріяльне оформлення, але не має плану змісту.

   До них належать два типи (різновиди):

   1. Єднальні голосні складних слів ***о***, ***е***, ***и***: *ліс**о**сте́п*, *житт**є**да́йний*, *сем**и**поверхо́вий*;
   2. Звукові прокладки між кореневою та афіксальною морфемами (або між двома суфіксальними): *шосе́**й**ний*, *америк**а́н**ський*. <sup>1</sup>
2. Словотворчий суфікс ***-н´-*** (****-ьнь*** < ***-inio***), а ***-шнʼ-*** — єго позіційний варіянт.
3. Суфіксальна одиниця ***-ш-*** (в *нікудишний*) і ***-іш-*** (ві *вранішній*).
4. Окремий суфікс ***-шн-***; складний суфікс ***-шній***; […] у прикметниках на дієприслівникових основ, «але на голосний, суфікс ***-шн-ий*** (< ***-шьн-ий*** < ****-ch-in***).

Однак як свідчить діялектний матеріял, не всяке ***-шнʼ-*** чи ***-ішнʼ-*** можна вважати суфіксом. Видїлено такі ґрупи утворів:

1. Похідні з суфіксом ***-нʼій*** (***-н-ий***):

   - *'л´ітюс´* «вторік» > *'л´іт´ушн´ій*; *ко'лис´* > *ко'лишн´ій*, пор. *ко'лисн´ій*, пор. інше — *ко'ишишн´ій* із ***-ишн´-ій***; *'ден´ішн´і*, *'данішні*, пор. *дьньшьнии* < прасл. **dьnьsь*; кінцевий твірної основи ***с´*** чергується з ***ш***;
   - *вто'р´ішн´ій* < *вто'р´ік*; *попе'решни* (*попе'решна 'пилка* «пилка, якою розрізають впоперек»), пор. *попе'речни*; ***ч*** > ***ш*** внаслїдок реґресівно дісімілації.
2. Похідні з суфіксом ***-шн(і(й)*** (якщо твірний прислівник закінчується голосним): *'тута* > *ту'ташні*, […]; пор. єдине утворення, можливо, з цим суфіксом від твірного прислівника на приголосний: *'тутай* > *ту'тайший*.
3. Утворення з суфіксом ***-ішн´-ій*** (якщо твірний прислівник закінчується приголосним або коли твірна основа усїкається): *'рано* > *'ран´ішн´ій*; *'поранок* > *пора'н´ішн´ій*, пор. *по<sup>у</sup>'ран´ічний*; *о'бʼід* (*в обʼід*) > *гоб'йід´ішн´і*; останнї два утворення, очевидно, відадʼєктивні: *о'бʼідн´ій* > *о'бʼідн´ішн´ій*; *по'луден´* «опівднї» > *пулуд'н´ішн´ій*; певно, цего ж творення і *'ден´ішн´ій*; цї прикметники вживаються переважно для позначення молока, видоєного в різну пору доби — вранцї, вдень і ввечерї.
4. Хоч західнополіський діялект видїляїть ся серед гинших богатьма окремими рисами, однак кожна говірка як складова частина цего говору має усталену мовну сістему, особливо в фонетіцї, що і призводить до існування різних аломорфів. Зауважимо, що не всї мовознавцї в цему випадку вживають термін [*аломорф*](//vue.gov.ua/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84), наприклад польський мовознавець [Януш Ріґер](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%88_%D0%A0%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80) вважає, що це все фонетичні варіянти відповідних суфіксів.

Аломорфи суфікса ***-ішн´-ій***:

- ***-ішн-ий***: *'ран´ішний*;
- ***-ишн´-ій***: *ве'чиришн´ій*, *'л´ітишн´і* «такий, що народився влїтку»;
- ***-ишн-ий***: *'ранишний*;
- ***-ешн´-ій***: *ту'тешн´ій*;
- ***-ечн´-ій***: *ту'течн´ій*;
- ***-ечн-и(й)***: *ту'течний*;
- ***-ошн´-ій***: *'тутошн´ій*;
- ***-ейш-и(й)*** (внаслїдок різних фонетичних змін): *ту'тейший*.

---

Якщо підсумувати, то ***-ш-*** зазвичай це інтерфікс або як таке явище самі тлумачимо. Однак в декотрих випадках може походити від ***сь*** чи ***ч*** < ***к***.

І якщо мова про *колишній*, то тут скорїш за всего тий *декотрий випадок*, а саме заміна ***сь*** → ***ш***, тобто *коли-сь-ній* → *коли-ш-ній*

---

Примітки

1. Пономаренко С. [Сучасна українська мова : Морфеміка. Дериватологія. Морфонологія : навчальний посібник](//dspace.chmnu.edu.ua/jspui/bitstream/123456789/64/1/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%A1.%20%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F.pdf#page=15) / С. Пономаренко ; відп. ред. О. В. Крутоголова. – Миколаїв : Вид-во ЧНУ ім. Петра Могили, 2017. – 300 с.